# Swift - Set Field to Null After UIButton Event

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a UIButton action that sends data to a PHP script based on the values in 4 text fields.  After the form is submitted, the fields should reset to null.  However, I'm having issues setting the fields back.  Here's my code - the variables to set null are username, password, name, and email at the bottom of the script.  Any help is appreciated:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var txtUsername: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtEmailAddress: UITextField!

    @IBAction func btnSubmit(sender: UIButton) {
        //Fields from app.
        var username = txtUsername.text
        var password = txtPassword.text
        var name = txtName.text
        var email = txtEmailAddress.text

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/phpPost/demo.php");
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

        let postString = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&name=" + name + "&email=" + email;

        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                println("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            println("******response = \(response)")

            // Print out response body
            let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("****response data=\(responseString)")

            //Convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
            var err: NSError?
            var myJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = myJSON {
                var name = parseJSON["name"] as? String
                println("name: \(name)")
            }

            username = ""
            password = ""
            name = ""
            email = ""
        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing nothing to change the textfields it should be like this. You are needed to access the text fields directly. What you are doing now is that copying the strings from them and change it.

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtUsername: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtEmailAddress: UITextField!

@IBAction func btnSubmit(sender: UIButton) {

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/phpPost/demo.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&name=" + name + "&email=" + email;

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        println("******response = \(response)")

        // Print out response body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("****response data=\(responseString)")

        //Convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
        var err: NSError?
        var myJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = myJSON {
            var name = parseJSON["name"] as? String
            println("name: \(name)")
        }

        self.txtUsername.text = ""
        self.txtPassword.text = ""
        self.txtName.text = ""
        self.txtEmailAddress.text = ""
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

If you need to clear out the text fields no matter what, you put set the text fields out of the block. because the block is called after the response asynchronously.

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtUsername: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtEmailAddress: UITextField!

@IBAction func btnSubmit(sender: UIButton) {

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/phpPost/demo.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&name=" + name + "&email=" + email;

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        println("******response = \(response)")

        // Print out response body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("****response data=\(responseString)")

        //Convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
        var err: NSError?
        var myJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = myJSON {
            var name = parseJSON["name"] as? String
            println("name: \(name)")
        }
    }

    self.txtUsername.text = ""
    self.txtPassword.text = ""
    self.txtName.text = ""
    self.txtEmailAddress.text = ""
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: I appreciate that Jason.  The other issue was that the fields needed set to "" below the task.resume() method.

Comment: Do you mean you need to clear those text fields no matter the responses are successful or not?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: Then you need to put setting text fields commands out of the block. Would you check the answer above? :)

Answer (score 2):

Do not set the string values to null or empty string or anything, set the `text` values of the `UITextField` properties:

```
txtUsername.text = ""
txtPassword.text = ""
txtName.text = ""
txtEmailAddress.text = ""
```

Changing `username` only changes the string scoped to the current function, it has no longer any relation to the textfield its value came from. Therefore changing its value has no effect on the textfield.